# ASP.Net String comparison - Weird issue - happens randomly

Tags: asp.net, string-comparison

I have a piece of code that determines whether a logged in user is a member or not. For some reason - even though the Roles collection has "Member" - the code reaches the final return statement.

This event is rare - and the exact circumstances are different each time (web.config refresh sometimes/ clearing up asp.net temp files sometimes) -

```
private bool isLoggedInUserMember()
{
    string[] Roles = { "Member", "Professional" }; //In real code - this is pulled from the db
    foreach (string role in Roles)
    {
        if (role.Trim().ToLower().Equals("member"))
            return true;
    }
    return false; //sometimes the code reaches here 
}
```

So my question is - are  you aware about any .net bugs which come up when using the Trim().ToLower() or any such sequence?

This is a ASP.Net Web Site application running on 3.5

Thanks!

Comment: Add some logging code to see what `Roles` is equal to in production. Chances are it *isn't* "Member".

Comment: Also use `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` instead of `ToLower` to perform case-insensitive string comparison.